# Solr return empty result when search "OMG!*"

Tags: solr, lucene, drupal-7, solr4

I am facing one issue using solr 4.9 with drupal-7 and search API. When I am searching with combination of exclamation point (!), then solr returns an empty result.

E.g:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=OMG!*&wt=json
```

The above query return empty result. However, in document there is data with this word:

```
1. "tm_title": [
          "OMG! Ranveer Singh admits to having a 'Casting Couch' experience "
        ]
2. "tm_title": [
          "OMG! Rajinikanth was supposed to dub for 'Dangal'"
        ]
```

**The result should return this both document as I am searching starting word "OMG!" and followed by anything(*).**

EDITED:
Following are the druapl search API title field configuration.
[image]

Comment: please share the field type used for the field tm_title? search depends how the field is been indexed?

Comment: Yeah, its Text type.

Comment: It would be good if you could share the definition of the fieldType ..fieldType where it will have defined the analyser and filter ....You will find the same in the schema.xml

Comment: Hi @AbhijitBashetti I added more details in question, which is drupal configuration for solr.

Answer (score 2):

When you're using wildcards, the analyzer sequence is mostly skipped. Since the content probably is indexed as "omg" (you can confirm this by using the analysis page of the admin interface), trying to match against tokens that start with "OMG!" won't work (it'll probably search for "omg!", since the lowercasefilter is multiterm aware).

If you drop the '!' from your wildcard, you'll probably get a hit - or if you drop the wildcard at all.

Comment: Yes...I too tried search with "!" and wildcard...it doesn't work...for example if I search for 'Brava!'...I get the result...and if I search with 'Brava!*' it doesn't get me the result...Good catch MatsLindh...

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh, When I only search with "OMG!" it is return me result.

Comment: Yes, because then the complete analysis chain runs, stripping the `!` and doing the same processing as when the content was indexed. When you're using a wildcard, multiple steps of that analysis chain is skipped (except for the filters that are multitermaware) - so the tokens won't match.